# How to compile CoreFoundation with Xcode from apple's source code?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, compilation, core-foundation

As is know to us all, iOS's CoreFoundation framework is open source and can be downloaded from:
http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/CF/CF-1153.18.tar.gz
http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/
I created a Xcode project and drag the source files to the project. Then I compile the code, I found some errors.
Who can tell me how to compile the CoreFoundation source code by using Xcode?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you can share the errors, that would help out tremendously.

Nevertheless, the open source version of CoreFoundation—called CFLite—is designed to be compiled with plain old `make`.

You can *probably* port CFLite over to an `xcodeproj` container, but you'd need to copy all of the `clang` and linker flags and such defined in the `Makefile`.